# Swift Framework only builds after a clean

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

So I have this framework called MyAuth, It build fine and when I import the .framework file into other apps everything works. However the project will fail to build every second time you build it until after i clean.

The error I get is `Umbrella header 'MyAuth.h' not found` and it points to a module.modulemap file which looks like:

```
framework module MyAuth {
    umbrella header "MyAuth.h"    <- Error on this line

    export *
    module * { export * }
}

module MyAuth.Swift {
    header "MyAuth-Swift.h"
    requires objc
}
```

But the header file does exist and is located in the root directory of the project.

Now if i do a clean and then build again it will succeed, but I have to clean my build folder every time i want to build the project which works but it's not ideal.

Is there any reason this would be happening?

Comment: Try reverting to the legacy build system?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so this took WAY to long to figure out.

Basically in header search paths and in library search paths I was recursively searching `$(SRCROOT)` and I had my build directory set to be made in the project directory. This meant after every build it would search the Build directory since it was included in `$(SRCROOT)`.

Changed my search paths and now it builds fine every time.

Answer (score 0):

Check is it Fat framework for device and simulator

Comment: It is not, it builds one or the other not both